# Inserting comas between String in Notepad++

Tags: csv, notepad++, text-files, addition

I want to know how can i add ',' (comas or other separator) if i have a data like this

Current Condition
[image: Current_Condition]

i want to add comas between the data in one line, so i can generate it into .csv and export to excel.

Expected Result
[image: Expected_Result]

Is there any thing that i can try to make it happen? I did replace all features from notepad++, and found out there are some numeric data that turn into ',' too.

Thank you :)

Comment: Please, don't post images, add the example as a text so we can test it.

Comment: Are these spaces only spaces and/or tabulations?

Answer (score 0):

It seems every number is followed by a single space. If that is the case, then you could simply do a search and replace - find every single space and replace with a comma (or a space and a comma).

Alternatively, depending on your CSV reader, you could set the delimiter to be a single space, in other words the reader would treat every space as a linebreak.

Edit: as you have clarified that there are multiple spaces, try this in notepad++:

Ctrl+H or Search>Replace. 
Select the regular expression radio button under 'search mode'.

Search for:

`+`
(one space followed by +)

Replace with:

`,` (single comma)

Comment: Thank for your answer, I did search-replace. and became like this in every line
SR000225,,,12500,,,,,4550000,,,,23/05/2020
 but the data is too hard to manage since it has 190.000++ data to delete excess commas.

Comment: Try this in notepad++:

ctrl+H or Search>Replace. Select the regular expression radio button under 'search mode'.

Search for 
 +
(one space followed by +) 
Replace with , (single comma)